# Add modal popup on multiple list elements

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, jquery, modal-popup

I would like to add modal functionality in a list of images wrapped in a `div`. It should work like so: when i click on a `span` element the next image should show in a modal. Html example below.

```
<?php foreach($datas as $data): ?>
    <div class="modal-thumbnail">
        <span class="modal-toggle">
            <img class='img-responsive' src='<?php echo $data->getImage(); ?>' alt='<?php echo $data->getAlt(); ?>'>
        </span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="inner">
                <img class='img-responsive-full' src='<?php echo $data->getImage(); ?>' alt='<?php echo $data->getAlt(); ?>'>
                <span class="text"><?php echo $data->getDesc(); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If more information is needed I will provide what is asked.

Thanks

Comment: are you using `bootstrap` modal functions?

Comment: I'm using the Magento2 modal widget functionality